# Is there a way to use a sweetAlert.js for confirm instead of the standard in the method during onbeforeexit()

Tags: javascript, intro.js

I am trying to use sweet alert to as a replacement for the standard JavaScript confirm dialog box. The issue I am experiencing is when I return the promise the method does not wait for the response it simply ends the tour.

I would like to see this method accept a promise and wait for the response. Is this possible?

I would expect after clicking no on the sweetAlert modal, that i would be returned to the tour as when using the standard javascript confirm('') method as shown here

```
Introjs().onbeforeexit(function() {

        var alertText;

    if (instance.data.whatstep < steps.length){
        alertText = 'Are you sure you want to leave the tour early'
    } else {
        alertText = properties.alert_text
    }
    
    var r = confirm (alertText)
    if (r == true){
        console.log('exit')

        if ( instance.data.whatstep < steps.length ){
            console.log('leaving early')
            instance.triggerEvent("user_left_tour")

        } else {
            console.log('not leaving early')
            instance.triggerEvent("user_finished_tour")
        }
        
        return r
        
    } else {
        console.log('dont exit')
        return r
    }

});
```

here is the 'onbeforeexit()' code I am ***trying to use*** that doesn't work

```
    Introjs().onbeforeexit(function() {
     const r = async function confirm(message) {
        return swal({
            text: 'are you sure',
            buttons: true
        });
    }
        console.log(r())
        return r()
    
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
```

This is avaliable in the SweetAlert 2
Here is the link for the same [Link](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples) the example you are looking for is **"A confirm dialog, with a function attached to the "Confirm"-button..."**

Comment: i have shared the solution above. i only have 1 issue left now! Thank you